# Detecting when the contents of a web page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, dom

This is the code I'm using at the moment

```
/*
 * Adjust content height so that it always fills browser height
 *
 * written by Tom Jenkinson
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    refreshContentSize(); //run initially

    $(window).resize(function() { //run whenever window size changes
        refreshContentSize();
    });

    setInterval('refreshContentSize()', 500); // in case content size changes. THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE
});

function refreshContentSize()
{
    var startPos = $("#content").position();
    var topHeight = startPos.top;
    var contentHeight = $("#content").outerHeight(true);
    var footerHeight = $("#footer").outerHeight(true);
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();    
    var spaceForContent = viewportHeight - footerHeight - topHeight;

    if (spaceForContent <= contentHeight)
    {
        var newHeight = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        var newHeight = spaceForContent - contentHeight;
    }
    $("#filler").css('height', newHeight);
    return; 
}
```

The site is http://wncba.co.uk/results and the script is at http://wncba.co.uk/results/javascript/fill-pagev2.js.

At the moment you can see that I'm using a timer to keep calling the `refreshContentSize()`. I am doing this because some of the content on the page can change dynamically meaning the page height will change.

Is there a handle for this like jquery's 'resize' so I don't need the timer?

Comment: From my understanding, you're trying to resize the height of your content. What I would use is VH (viewport height) and VW (viewport width) units for the contents container. For its children, I would use %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really verify what the code does since when I checked, the filler is always 0px. But I assume your code checks for the surrounding elements in an interval and updates the filler height accordingly.

I have some tips for your code:

```
//shorthand .ready using the jQuery namespace
//and using the $ as the inner namespace
jQuery(function ($) {

    //cache repeatedly used references
    var content = $("#content"),
        footer = $("#footer"),
        $window = $(window),
        filler = $("#filler");

    // - place functions inside the ready handler to avoid globals
    // - always hand over a function reference to a timer and never an eval-able string
    // - since 500ms is fast enough, resize and an init wouldn't be needed
    //   a human sees 200ms as "instant" and at least 700ms a significant lag
    //   somewhere in between is the "sweet spot"
    setInterval(function () {
        var startPos = content.position(),
            topHeight = startPos.top,
            contentHeight = content.outerHeight(true),
            footerHeight = footer.outerHeight(true),
            viewportHeight = $window.height(),
            spaceForContent = viewportHeight - footerHeight - topHeight,
            //JS has a function scope. Any variable declared anywhere is visible
            //everywhere in the containing function. Therefore, it's better to
            //declare them outside operations
            newHeight = 0; //default to 0

        //overwrite 0 if conditions state otherwise
        if (spaceForContent > contentHeight) {
            newHeight = spaceForContent - contentHeight
        }

        //so it's 0 or some other value
        filler.css('height', newHeight);

    }, 500);
});
```

Packed version:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var content = $("#content"),
        footer = $("#footer"),
        $window = $(window),
        filler = $("#filler");
    setInterval(function () {
        var startPos = content.position(),
            topHeight = startPos.top,
            contentHeight = content.outerHeight(true),
            footerHeight = footer.outerHeight(true),
            viewportHeight = $window.height(),
            spaceForContent = viewportHeight - footerHeight - topHeight,
            newHeight = 0;
        if (spaceForContent > contentHeight) {
            newHeight = spaceForContent - contentHeight
        }
        filler.css('height', newHeight)
    }, 500)
});
```

You might want to check out [Mutation Observers API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) which gives you the ability to listen to changes in the DOM. It's not yet supported across browsers but just included it if ever you are interested.

Also, I think it's better that you rethink your layout - one which only relies on plain HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks. The Mutation Observers API looks really interesting. The site was originally just html and css but then I thought I'd make it look a bit neater with some js. It should still look and work fine if js is disabled though. I've seen the '$' being passed into the function before but never understood what it meant. Please can you explain what the 'inner namespace' is and how the '$' relates to it. Thanks :)

Comment: @TomJenkinson jQuery uses 2 global namespaces, `jQuery` and `$`. But other frameworks also use `$` which causes conflicts. Also, developers tend to use `$` more often since it's shorter. To address both issues, use the `jQuery` global to initiate the DOM ready callback. Inside the callback, jQuery passes itself as first parameter. To address the second issue, we use `$` for the passed jQuery. That way, the local `$` inside the callback is jQuery, while the `$` outside can be used by any framework.